# EditText cursor blink only when focused

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an `EditText`.

I want the `EditText`'s cursor blink only when the user types some text.

I've tried `OnFocusChangeListener`, but this doesn't take effect.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The default behavior is for the cursor to blink when its in focus. What kind of behavior are you looking for? It sounds a lot like the default one.

Comment: No, i'm playing with my `ListView`, which es below the `EditText`, and still the cursor keeps blinking.